# PostgreSQL - why doesn't it uses existing index where primary key is created?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

**IBM DB2**

```
C:\>db2 create table public.tab1 (id int not null, col1 int not null)
C:\>db2  create unique index tab1_ix on public.tab1 (id) include (col1)
C:\>db2  alter table public.tab1 add primary key (id)
SQL0598W  Existing index "IN1139.TAB1_IX" is used as the index for the primary
key or a unique key.  SQLSTATE=01550
```

It is just info, that existing index was used.

---

**POSTGRESQL**

```
db=# create table public.tab1 (id int not null, col1 int not null);
db=# create unique index tab1_ix on public.tab1 (id) include (col1);
db=# alter table public.tab1 add primary key (id);

db=# \d public.tab1;
                Table "public.tab1"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer |           | not null |
 col1   | integer |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "tab1_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "tab1_ix" UNIQUE, btree (id) INCLUDE (col1)
```

PostgreSQL created additional index for primary key.

Why is this important?
a) In many cases in explain I have seen if primary key is created then database uses primary key index for queries. But if I drop primary key then unique index and queries run way faster (because of Index Only Scan).
b) Additional disk space is used for additional primary key index.
c) Every update/insert/delete and two indexes must be updated instead of one.

Questions:

1. Is there a way I can force PostgreSQL database to use existing index, when primary key is added on table with existing unique index (like in IBM Db2)?
2. Is there a way I can force PostgreSQL to use unique index (and so use Index Only Scan) instead of primary key index (and using only Index Scan) when queries are executed?

Comment: It has its own syntax if you want to use an existing index.  See the docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html

Comment: Index-only scans are only effective when many pages of the table are marked as all visible.  If that is the case, no force should be needed.  Check pg_class.relallvisible, and run VACUUM if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't automatically use an existing unique index for the primary key; you have to do it yourself:

```
ALTER TABLE public.tab1 ADD PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX tab1_ix;
```

Of course, you could also *not* create the index in the first place, since a primary key will add its own index, as you see.

Comment: Thanks this works fine. But now additional problem appears when dropping primary key. In IBM Db2 database there is syntax: "ALTER TABLE public.tab1 DROP PRIMARY KEY" and after this unique index I have created still exists. But on PostgreSQL I see this syntax does not exists and I have to use "ALTER TABLE public.tab1 DROP CONSTRAINT tab1_ix", but if I do this beside primary key, index is also dropped. How to drop primary key without dropping unique index?

Comment: Different database management systems speak different SQL dialects. Seems like DB2 violates the SQL standard here.

Comment: Do you have SQL standard definition for drop primary key syntax? I tried to search for https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/en/#iso:std:76584:en but interesting SQL standard is only available for purchase.

Comment: The PostgreSQL syntax conforms to the SQL standard in this case. Yes, you have to buy the standard.